# DDMathParser not working in Obj-C project using CocoaPods

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods, ddmathparser

I have an Obj-C project with CocoaPods. Now I need to use DDMathParser, written in Swift. But can not import DDMathParser correctly. When I add new Swift file to the project, it works fine. DDMathParser is not working even in swift file I've created. Here's a bit of my code:

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "test-Swift.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    SwiftTest *test = [[SwiftTest alloc] init];
    [test run];

    NSLog(@"%@", [@"5 + 5" numberByEvaluatingString]);

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

What I must do to make it work?

P.S. Bridging header created and working. In build settings "Defines Modules" set to YES

CocoaPods file:

```
pod 'AFNetworking'
pod 'DDMathParser'
use_frameworks!
```

Comment: Please add your Cocoapods file.

Comment: Please also describe what "doesn't work" means. Does it fail to build? If so, what's the build failure? Does it fail at runtime? If so, what's the runtime error? Etc.

Comment: It fails to build. Looks like DDMathParser's classes havent imported yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
pod 'DDMathParser'
```

This implies that you're using version 3.0 of DDMathParser, which was recently re-written in Swift, and in which the method `numberByEvaluatingString` does not exist. It was renamed to `evaluate`.

Comment: It doesn't work too. I think there's a problem in importing DDMathParser from CocoaPods, not in using it